# Redirect action with parameters in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, redirect

In my ASP.Net project I'm trying to redirect a page to other action after select a row table and click on a button. So I have this code:

**JQuery:**

```
function editItem(tableId, url) {
    if ($("#" + tableId + " .selected").exists()) {

        var thisRowId = $("#" + tableId + " .selected").attr("id");

        window.location.replace(url, { operation: "edit", carId: thisRowId });
    }
};

//more code
```

**View (ManagementCar):**

```
@model myProject.Model.Car.Car[]

<table class="table" id="tableCars">
    <thead>
        @*some code to header*@
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        foreach (var item in Model)
        {
        <tr id="@(item.Id)" onclick="selectRow('tableCars', '@(item.Id)')">
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.OwnerName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @(item.IsSold == true ? "Yes" : "No")
            </td>
        </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
<br />
<button id="btEdit" type="button" class="disable" onclick="editItem('tableCars','CarOperation')">Edit</button>
```

**Controller:**

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult CarOperation(string operation, int carId)
{
    //some code...

    return RedirectToAction("ManagementCar", "Backoffice");
}
```

But I have a Server Error after redirect saying `carId` parameter is null. I debug my jquery and that parameter isn't null. I tried also doing

```
$.get(url, { operation: "edit", carId: thisRowId });
```

instead

```
window.location.replace(url, { operation: "edit", carId: thisRowId });
```

but it don't redirect.
How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I finally solved the problem with a new url routing config and the following code:

**My RouteConfig:**

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "ManipulatingCar",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{operation}/{carId}"
);
```

**My JQuery:**

```
editItem = function (tableId, url) {
    if ($("#" + tableId + " .selected").exists()) {

        var thisRowId = $("#" + tableId + " .selected").attr("id");

        var fullUrl = url + "/edit/" + thisRowId;

        window.location = fullUrl;
    }
};
```

Basically, controller action parameters must match with the configurations specified in `RouteConfig.cs`

Answer (score 0):

set it by giving it a new value like this.

```
window.location = window.location.replace(url, "shouldBeAstringNotAJsonObject");
```

Comment: sorry, actually I got an error. It redirects me to a undefined page like: `https://localhost/myProject/Backoffice/undefined` . I don't understand why...?

Comment: javascript replace function takes 2 strings as paramaters. you're passing a json object on the second parameter. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp

Comment: what i meant, you're not supposed to be passing a json object on your replace function. window.location.replace(url, "shouldBeAstringNotAJsonObject");

Comment: and I tried with a string but I got this error: "The parameters dictionary contains a null entry" (...)

Answer (score 0):

The problem with using `window.location` is that the referrer is not passed on the request as this behaviour simply mimics a new request as if you had typed the URL into the address bar.  If you intend to use website analytics, a reliable referrer will be quite important.  I use jQuery to generate a dynamic link upon which I call `click()`.

```
var url = '/my/url';
$('<a href="' + url + '"></a>')[0].click();
```

Notice I `click()` the underlying element not the jQuery selected object, the reason being that a jQuery click only raises the event and the href is not navigated to whereas indexing to the element and clicking that will cause the same behaviour you would expect as if you had actually clicked a link on the page.

I have put together a [jQuery.navigate plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/navigate/) that neatly wraps this up and abstracts your site map away from your UI logic, which you might find useful.  For example, using my plugin would mean you could remove your `editItem` function altogether and simply change your markup to something like this?

```
<tr id="@(item.Id)" onclick="$.navigate('to', 'edit', { id : '@(item.Id)' })">
```